# Use angular pipe on input element

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have created this pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'euro'
})
export class EuroPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(salary: string, currency: string = '*EUR*') {
    return parseInt(salary) * 0.89 + ' ' + currency;
  }
}
```

I have a template with an input field

```
<input type="text">
```

Is there a way that I can implement my pipe on the value of the input field?

Comment: you can bind the input value of the field and use the pipe in controller.

Comment: try an educated guess `<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="property | euro">`